# Relative path for navigation bar

Tags: html, menu, navigation, relative-path, filepath

using dreamweaver whole file is in finalgate folder ,i have folder with name GATE in it which i have some php files, i connected those files with the navigation bar (nav bar is in folder named common)

```
<li class="nav"> <a class="drop-nav-link" href="gate/gate-preexam-eligibility.php">Eligibility</a> </li>

<li class="nav"> <a class="drop-nav-link" href="gate/gate-preexam-qualifyingdisciplines.php"> Qualifing Disiplane </a> </li>
```

.
**small part of navigation code**

there is a menu named gate, under which submenu pre-exam ,under the pre-exam there is a submenu named eligibility, when i clicked that it opened with the link http://localhost/finalgate/gate/gate-preexam-eligibility.php

but from this page when i go to another submenu of pre-exam called qualifing disciplane the link shows nothing and in the link automatic extra gate is comes

link http://localhost/finalgate/gate/gate/gate-preexam-qualifyingdisciplines.php
it shows not found.

can anyone help me to explain how to give the path correctly, i am new in this field.

Answer (score 0):

See how your `href` attribute is `gate/gate-preexam-qualifyingdisciplines.php`? That's what we call a relative URL. We call it this because it tells you the URL of the page you're linking to *in relation to* the URL of the page you're currently on. That is, if we are on some page like `http://localhost/finalgate/index.php`, it will append your `href` to the URL of the current page after the final folder of your path. In this case, when clicking on your link for Qualifying Disiplane, your `a` element would link to `http://localhost/finalgate/gate/gate-preexam-qualifyingdisciplines.php` because the final folder of the current location is `http://localhost/finalgate/`.

However, when linking to the same `href` from `http://localhost/finalgate/gate/gate-preexam-eligibility.php`, your `a` element would link to a different URL, because in this case, the final folder is `http://localhost/finalgate/gate/`, making your complete destination URL `http://localhost/finalgate/gate/gate/gate-preexam-qualifyingdisciplines.php`.

To fix this, put the absolute URL (`http://localhost/finalgate/gate/gate-preexam-qualifyingdisciplines.php`, not `gate/gate-preexam-qualifyingdisciplines.php`) as your `href` attribute instead. This way your links will always link to the same URL no matter what page you're currently on.